# Map Kit: info button on flipside view shown in front of the map

Tags: xcode, ios4, mapkit

I have a mapkit on my app but the info button is hidden behind it, can I do something so the info button is in front of the map view???

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using interface builder, change the view type to a tree (might be able to do this in grid mode as well) and rearrange the list of items on the view so that the info button is above the mapView (can't remember if z-order is top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top).

If your adding the button in code.  It should be in front automatically but if thats not working, you can always call bringSubviewToFront:infoButton on its parent view.